# AngularJS exclude filter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a search box using angular:

```
<input type="text"
typeahead="item.name for item in list |
filter: $viewValue:comparator | orderBy: '+name'"/>
```

I want to add another filter to exclude certain items from another array.
Something like:

```
... | exclude: items in excludedList
```

I don't want to use `ng-hide`; I'm specifically looking for a filter to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This look like a job for a custom filter:

```
.filter('excludeItemsByName', function () {
        return function (items, excludedList) {
            var ret = [];
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                if (excludedList.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {
                    ret.push(item);
                }
            });
            // or you could use Array.prototype.filter() in browsers that support it
            return ret;
        };
    })
```

Then

```
<input type="text"
typeahead="item.name for item in list |
filter: $viewValue:comparator | excludeItemsByName:['excludeThis','excludeThat'] orderBy: '+name'"/>
```

(This assumes excludedList will be a flat list of strings; it should be clear enough how to extend this to support excluded objects instead...)

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters

Comment: This might fail in case of array of objects. Right?

Comment: @manu29.d As always, it depends on if you're expecting an exclusion by reference or by equality.